#  Add custom HTML attributes to generated controls

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I just want to add a placeholder for my generated `input` element.

This is what being generated

```
<input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Username field is required." id="Username" name="Username" type="text" value="">
```

This is the code that generates HTML output

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Username)
```

Of course I can just remove the generated code and write it by myself just including the necessary fields, however maybe it is possible to just pass some kind of parameter to `EditorFor` that will add `placeholder` attribute to it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use @Html.TextBoxFor instead of @HtmlEditorFor and then write htmlAttributes like this:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Username, new { placeholder = "Username..." })
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => model.Username, new { data_val_attribute = "value" });
```

Most of the helpers will have an overload that accepts an anonymous object as the last parameter for specifying attributes in the generated markup.

Comment: `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Username, new { placeholder = "Username..." })` does not work.

Answer (score 0):

@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Username, new { placeholder = "Username..." }) should work, unless your model is not empty. Have you checked if your model is empty?